# Suppress the root element in COBOL JSON GENERATE

Tags: json, cobol

I'm using the JSON GENERATE statement with IBM Cobol like this (shortened) example:

```
JSON GENERATE WS-JSON                                    
         FROM  CBL-GROUP      
     COUNT IN WS-JSON-LEN                                
      NAME OF  FIELD1 is "name"
               FIELD2 is "address"
```

It generates a JSON-string with "CBL-GROUP" as a root element:

```
{
  "CBL-GROUP": {
    "name": "Smith",
    "address": "New Orleans"
  }
}
```

Actually I don't want the root element "CBL-GROUP" in my JSON-document, I only want name & address.
Tried the SUPPRESS für JSON GENERATE, but it didn't work (wouldn't even compile).
Is there a way to generate the JSON without the root element?

Comment: According to [IBM's documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-json-generate-statement), SUPRESS only works for subordinate elements.  You could try NAME OF identifier IS OMITTED.

Comment: Very cool, that seems to work! I had tried something similar **NAME IS ""**, but the compiler did not allow the empty string. Thanks.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Can you please make an answer out of your comment, allowing Alexander to mark it as excepted?

Answer (score 0):

According to [IBM's documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-json-generate-statement), SUPRESS only works for subordinate elements. You could try NAME OF identifier IS OMITTED.